# Embedded YouTube videos don't go fullscreen on HTML5 player

Tags: google-chrome, youtube

I'm trying to view YouTube videos embedded in Facebook pages on fullscreen. I am on Chrome and the videos are playing in the HTML5 player. When I hit fullscreen, the browser itself goes full screen and the video is nowhere to be seen.

This does not happen when I'm on Youtube, so it doesn't seem like a browser specific problem. On other websites (I tried mental floss and twitter), embedded videos play on the HTML5 player, but do not show the Fullscreen option.

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 6):

Html5 fullscreen requires the iframe to have an `allowfullscreen` attribute on the iframe to work correctly. If the website embedding the iframe hasn't added this, the full screen won't work

Comment: I checked the source. It does have `allowfullscreeen=1` on it. And I just checked another YouTube embedded video on Facebook - this one goes to fullscreen, no problems. I think this might be a problem with the video, though I can't say for sure. Any other tests I can run?

Comment: This solved an issue I was having with embedding youtube videos; In my case I got a message saying that fullscreen was disabled rather than the browser trying to go full screen as the original question mentions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be Facebook-specific.

On the Facebook home feed, HTML5 videos don't seem to go into fullscreen properly. Inspecting the source, the iframe is inside a `hidden_elem` div which has `display: none`. Making this visible restores the video. Interestingly, it *does* just work if you view the same video on a timeline (Profile or Page.)

You can force Flash player with a browser add-on.

Comment: Thank you. I'll test this solution the next time I face the problem. After a long time, I faced it yesterday but bypassed it by opening the video in YouTube.

Comment: Just ran a test, it did not work. The entire Chrome window goes to fullscreen, video plays, I guess (I can hear the audio). I tried digging around, but the `<div class="html5-video-content">` does not seem to have any `display:none` in the hierarchy. What could be the cause?